# Can't run the file via terminal on PyCharm works perfectly

Tags: python, python-3.x

I try to understand where is my problem.
This is my project

```
└── test_folder
    |___ __init__.py
    ├── foled_1
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── file_1.py
    └── foled_2
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── file_2.py
```

When I try to run the script of file_1.py from the PyCharm, everything works perfectly for me.
But when I try to run this file via terminal (python3 file_1.py) I got the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file_1.py", line 1, in <module>
    from foled_2.file_2 import a
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'foled_2'
```

The script of file_1.py is:

```
from foled_2.file_2 import a

print(a)
print("Hello")
```

The script of file_2.py is:

```
a = 2
```

Comment: I'd guess what pycharm does is running `python3 foled_1/file_1.py` from `test_folder` (instead of from `test_folder/foled_1`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import a module from a relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279237/import-a-module-from-a-relative-path)

Answer (score 0):

if you run the file from test folder like `python foled_1/file_1.py` it will work.

why this is not working?

this is because in pycharm you have defined test_folder as base project folder.so
      whenever you run a script, it will run from that folder , ie it take termnial current       path as that base folder.

also in your code you have mentioned that you need `foled_2` , since you are in foled_1 path and running script there, python is unable to locate the `foled_2` folder/package.

solutuion

so if you want to run your script, run it from testfolder in terminal. 
  `python foled_1/file_1.py`

Comment: I still get the ImportError

Comment: I found the solution that works for me. python3 -m foled_1.file_1

Comment: @andrew in your code, you need to do relative import like, `from .foled_2.file_2 import a`